# Is there a way to make a custom return message when LimitRequestBody is exceeded?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, apache, file-upload

i am using LimitRequestBody to cut of the user if he goes past my upload limit. IT returns a message like this

Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource
/index.php
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
logo

Im not totally sure what it wants here.. but it does get triggered if the user exceeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LimitRequestBody is at the Apache level (ie, never hits PHP), you need to replace the error document at the Apache level.  The way you do that is with [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#errordocument).

From the output `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`, it looks like there is an ErrorDocument set up, but Apache can't find it.

Basically, you will need something like:

```
ErrorDocument 413 /request-too-large.php
```

The request-too-large.php file will probably get a standard GET request - any POST parameters will be lost, but you can look inside `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` to see if there is anything else left over from the original request.

It may take a while to get this right in terms of executing PHP for the error document.  If you can't come right doing it directly with PHP, use a plain HTML page, and then set up a META Redirect and/or JavaScript redirect to send you to a PHP page.

You can also set it with a full URL - this will use a client-side redirect.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the responds. Unfortunatlly i tried to do ErrorDocument 413 /error_file.php but 413 does not seem to be work..  all the others do like 500 or 404 but not 413

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?  There used to be a few bugs with 413 handling because the content length wasn't reset before doing the new request.  Also, did you try the client-side redirect instead (with the full URL)?